# Uploaded image is not showing in React-strap carousel

Tags: reactjs, upload, slider, carousel

i have one component for Showing the List of Images and in that one method OnfileChange shown below:

```
onFileUplod = (body: any) => {
    const response = new ApiHelper().MakeRequestWithBody(
        "SftpImage",
        "PUT",
        body
    );
    response.then((ResponseText: any) => {
        let response = JSON.parse(ResponseText);
        const { curruntImageData } = this.state;
        let index = this.state.sftpImages.findIndex(el => el.imageId === this.state.curruntImageData.imageId);

        this.state.sftpImages[index] = response.data;
        this.getAllSftpImages();
        this.setState({
            activeIndex:index,  
            curruntImageData: curruntImageData,
            showModal:true
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.getAllSftpImages();
        console.log("Error caught in catch", error);
    });
}
```

And this is my Sftp Component :

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import { ISftpImage } from '../../models/SftpImages';

import {
    Modal,
    ModalBody,
    Carousel,
    CarouselControl,
    CarouselItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { ApiHelper } from '../../utils/api';


declare var React360: any;

export interface IModalProps {
    curruntImage: ISftpImage;
    Images: ISftpImage[];
    activeIndex: number;
    getAllSftpImages: () => any;
    onFileUplod:(body:any)=>void;
    showModel:boolean
}

export interface IModalState {
    showModal: boolean;
    activeIndex: number,
    curruntImage: ISftpImage,
    loading: boolean,
    actionModal: boolean,
}



class SftpComponent extends Component<IModalProps, IModalState> {
    private refFileUpload = createRef<any>();
    constructor(props: IModalProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            showModal: false,
            actionModal: false,
            activeIndex: 0,
            curruntImage: {
                imageId: 0,
                currentUrl: '',
                retouchUrl: '',
                imageName: '',
                statusId: 0,
                createdBy: 0,
                updatedBy: 0,
                updatedDate: '',
                createdDate: '',
                caption: '',
                urlMaxSizeThumbnail: '',
                is360Image: false,
                urlexIfDetail: '',
                comment: '',
                isdownloaded: false,
                isretouched: false
            }
        };
    }


componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        activeIndex: this.props.activeIndex,
        curruntImage: this.props.curruntImage,
        // showModal:this.props.showModel
    })
}

handleModalShowClick = (modeltype: string) => {
    if (modeltype == "imagemodel") {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true
        })
    }
    if (modeltype == "upload") {
        this.setState({
            actionModal: true
        })
    }
}
handleModalCloseClick = (modeltype: string) => {
    if (modeltype == "imagemodel") {
        this.setState({
            showModal: false
        })
    }
    if (modeltype == "upload") {
        this.setState({
            actionModal: false
        })
    }
}

next = () => {
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === this.props.Images.length - 1 ? 0 : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
    const propertyImage = this.props.Images[nextIndex];
    this.setState({
        curruntImage: propertyImage,
        activeIndex: nextIndex,
    })
}
previous = () => {
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? this.props.Images.length - 1 : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
    const propertyImage = this.props.Images[nextIndex];
    this.setState({
        curruntImage: propertyImage,
        activeIndex: nextIndex,

    })
}
handleModalSubmitClick = (action: string) => {
    if (action === "download") {
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
            actionModal: false,
            showModal: true
        })
        let item = this.state.curruntImage;
        let url = item.currentUrl
        let ext = '.jpg';
        let imageId = item.imageId
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            cache: 'no-cache',
        }
        ).then(this.parseBlob)
            .then((response: Blob) => {

                FileSaver.saveAs(response, imageId + ext)
                let curruntImage = this.state.curruntImage;
                curruntImage.isdownloaded = true
                const res = new ApiHelper().MakeRequest(
                    "SftpImage/" + imageId,
                    "PUT",
                );
                this.setState({
                    curruntImage: curruntImage,
                    loading: false,
                    showModal:true
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                })
            });
    }
    if (action === "upload") {
        this.refFileUpload.current.click()
    }
}

parseBlob = (response: Response) => {
    return response.blob();
};

onFileChange = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({loading: true });
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('ImageId', String(this.state.curruntImage.imageId));
    body.append('RetouchImageFile', file);
    this.props.onFileUplod(body);
    this.setState({loading: false });
}

render() {

    if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
            <div className="jtb_background jtb_page_height">

                <div className="container-fluid  heighvh100">
                    <div className="spinnerwrapper"><i className="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
    const slides = this.props.Images.map((item: any, index: number) => {
        const url = item.isretouched ? item.retouchUrl : item.currentUrl
        return (

            <CarouselItem
                key={item.imageId}
                className="item"
                tag="div"
            >
                <div className="jtb_carousel_height">
                    <ul className={item.is360Image ? 'jtb_property_big_img360' : 'jtb_property_big_img'}>
                        <li className="slider_img_jtb">
                            {item.is360Image ?
                                <iframe src={"/React360/index.html?url=" + url} height="700px" width="100%" /> :
                                <img src={url} className="img-fluid max_img_height" id="imageSliderTemp" />}
                            <ul className="img_desc_jtb">
                                <li><span> {this.state.activeIndex + 1}</span><span>/</span><span>{this.props.Images.length}</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </CarouselItem>
        );
    });
    const imageDetails = this.state.curruntImage.urlexIfDetail ? JSON.parse(this.state.curruntImage.urlexIfDetail) : {};
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul className="img_collage" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowClick('imagemodel')}>
                <li className="position-relative" >
                    <img src={this.props.curruntImage.urlMaxSizeThumbnail}
                        alt={this.props.curruntImage.caption} />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.showModal} toggle={() => this.handleModalCloseClick('imagemodel')}
                modalClassName={' propertyslidermodal modal_full_jtb serachresultmodal '}
                contentClassName={'jtb_popup_height sftpmodel'}
                className={'modal-dialog-centered'}
            >
                <ModalBody>
                    <div className="row slidernewweap">
                        <div className="col-lg-12 jtb_popup_close">
                            <button type="button" className="close" onClick={() => this.handleModalCloseClick('imagemodel')}>
                                <img src="/images/close.png" alt="Close" /></button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-8" id="slider">
                            <Carousel activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex} next={this.next} previous={this.previous} className="full_thumbnail_slider full-popup-n" tag="div" interval={false} autoPlay={false} slide={true}>
                                {slides}
                                <div className="carousel_nxt_prv_arw">
                                    <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} className="carousel-control left" />
                                    <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next}
                                        className="carousel-control right" />
                                </div>
                            </Carousel>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-4 sideinfo">
                            <ul className="imageinfowrapper">
                                <li className="jtb_img_desc">
                                    <ul className="small_detail">
                                        <li>
                                            <span>Created Date</span>
                                            <label>{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }).format(new Date(this.props.curruntImage.createdDate))}</label>
                                        </li>
                                        {
                                            imageDetails && Object.keys(imageDetails).map((key: any, index: number) => (
                                                <li key={index}><span>{key}</span>
                                                    <label>{imageDetails[key]}</label>
                                                </li>
                                            ))
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div className="rightsideprpfooter">
                                <ul className="jtb_function_btn">
                                    <li>
                                        <button title="Download" onClick={() => this.handleModalSubmitClick('download')}>
                                            <img src="/images/download.png" alt="Download" />
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <button
                                            className="file_upload_jtb"
                                            title="Upload"
                                            disabled={this.state.curruntImage.isdownloaded ? false : true}
                                            onClick={() => this.handleModalShowClick('upload')}>

                                            <img src="/images/upload.png" alt="upload" />
                                            <input type="file"
                                                ref={this.refFileUpload}
                                                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                                                onInput={(event) => { this.onFileChange(event) }}
                                                onClick={(event: any) => { event.target.value = null }} />
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
            {
                this.state.actionModal ?
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.actionModal} toggle={() => this.handleModalCloseClick('upload')} modalClassName={'jtb_small_popup '} className={'modal-dialog-centered'}>
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <div className="action_text_jtb">
                                    <h3>Upload photo?</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="action_text">
                                    <p>The picture will be replaced. Are you sure you want to Upload new photo?</p>
                                </div>
                                <ul className="action_btn_jtb">
                                    {
                                        <React.Fragment>
                                            <li><button type="button" className="btn cancl_btn" onClick={() => this.handleModalCloseClick('upload')} >Cancel</button></li>
                                            <li><button type="button" className="btn jtb_red_btn" onClick={() => this.handleModalSubmitClick('upload')}>OK</button></li>
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                    }

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Modal>
                    : ''
            }
        </React.Fragment>

    )


}
}
```

export default SftpComponent;

now the problem is when I click on the upload button and select any image the slider close automatically and the uploaded image is not shown in the image list, I have to refresh the page for that, I want is that, I don't want to close the slider and the uploaded image is updated in the current slide but its not affecting properly

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this type of error.

Solution: your component is not waiting for your image upload action. before it gets completed it runs the whole process it is rendering further code.so you are not getting your image in images.

So. try to add an async function that runs on the backend and gives you proper results.